# Странно работает cin.get() после обработки ctrl+c

Tags: c++, signal, cin

Суть программы в том, что пользователь вводит строку, которая посимвольно считывается и выводится на экран.
Реализована обработка ctrl+c, в результате которой пользователь выбирает, завершить ли программу. Если он хочет продолжить работу, то выводится строка "Продолжение ввода...", и функция close_handler(int sig) завершается. Функция cin.get() ожидает ввода, следовательно в потоке нет мусорных символов, но ввод происходит неправильно

**Вопрос: почему после обработки ctrl+c данные не считываются правильным образом?**

Пример правильной работы:
ввод: abcde
вывод: abcde

Пример неправильной работы:
ввод: ctrl+c
вывод: Вы уверены, что хотите выйти? Введите YES, чтобы завершить программу
ввод: no
вывод: Продолжение ввода...
ввод: abcde
вывод: de

Ожидаемое поведение:
ввод: ctrl+c
вывод: Вы уверены, что хотите выйти? Введите YES, чтобы завершить программу
ввод: no
вывод: Продолжение ввода...
ввод: abcde
вывод: abcde

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

void print_str()
{
  cout << "Введите строку: " << endl << endl;
  string str;
  char c = cin.get();
  while (c != '\n')
  {
    str += c;
    c = cin.get();
  }
  cout << str << endl;
}

void close_handler(int sig){
    cout << "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти? Введите YES, чтобы завершить программу" << endl;
    string ans;
    char c = cin.get();
    while (c != '\n')
    {
      ans += c;
      c = cin.get();
    }
    if (ans == "YES")
      exit(0);
    else
      cout << "Продолжение ввода..." << endl;
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGINT, close_handler);
  print_str();
  return 0;
}
```

Ссылка на код: https://repl.it/@DmitriiNiechipo/stackoverflow-question-0

Comment: Ты вот тут порпустил кусок кода с циклом: `char c = cin.get();
    str += c;`

Comment: [Тут](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) список так называемых *signal safety* функций, т.е. тех, которые можно использовать в обработчике сигналов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения С++ в обработчике сигнала **нельзя** работать ни с одним объектом со статическим временем хранения кроме объектов типа `std::atomic`. Это включает в том числе объекты стандартных потоков `std::cin` и `std::cout`. В противном случае это **UB**.

Также в обработчике сигнала нельзя пользоваться функциями стандартной библиотеки окромя следующих:

```
std::abort()
std::_Exit()
std::quick_exit()
std::signal() // только для того же сигнала
```

В С++17 этот список немного расширили, но принципиально ничего не поменялось. Так что вводом-выводом пользоваться всё равно будет **нельзя**.

---

Другими словами, всё что можно сделать в обработчике сигнала — это установить какой-либо флаг `std::atomic` и/или завершить программу. В конкретных ОС можно сделать немного больше, но ограничения всё равно довольно строгие.

---

См. [Подробности на cppreference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal)

Comment: А если хочется? В винде же командная строка спрашивает на ctrl+c требуется ли завершить весь батник.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда ввод-вывод надо делать не через стандартные потоки, а через системные средства, чтобы его можно было безопасно прервать сигналом и задать вопрос уже синхронно... а ещё я не знаю, как именно реализован запуск батника — у меня есть подозрение, что вопрос там выводит сам терминал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у каждой ОС свои функции, которые она дополнительно разрешает использовать в сигналах… но это уже за пределами стандарта языков Си/С++ и надо смотреть документацию по конкретным ОС… в частности на linux и других *nix'ах можно выводить и вводить через обычный `write()` и `read()`, а также [делать много-что ещё](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Что-как именно на win — я на вскидку не скажу, но точно нельзя использовать файловые потоки, нельзя аллоцировать память и, как следствие, все функции семейства `printf`…

Comment: @Qwertiy, чтение: `read(STDIN_FILENO /*0*/, buf, buf_sz);`, запись: `write(STDOUT_FILENO /*1*/, buf, buf_sz);`... по запросу «низкоуровневый ввод вывод Си» в гугле должно много-чего быть... при этом формировать и парсить строки приходится вручную в буфере на стеке... всё это относительно геморройно, так что в обработчиках сигналов редко бывает какая-то сложная логика...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102458/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-fat-zer).